# Get data from XML and display in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to display XML data as a text.
I'm using javascript for getting image data and that works fine but I couldn't manage to display text data.

Here is the XML:

```
<vector>
<pic>
    <ad>01-Wedding.jpg</ad>
    <txt>1</txt>
    <met>Tasarim 1</met>
</pic>
</vector>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

xmlhttp.open("GET","resimler.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("pic");
    i=0;

    function displayFoto(){
        ad=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ad")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        txt=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("met")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("showFoto").src="img/" + ad;
        document.getElementById("metintext").value=txt;}

    function next(){
        if (i<x.length-1){
          i++;
          displayFoto();}}

    function previous(){
        if (i>0){
          i--;
          displayFoto();}}
    </script>
```

and here is the div:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="inner-tasarim">
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li><img id='showFoto'/></li>
    </ul>                
    <span class="arrow previous"><img onClick="previous()" src="img/arrow-prev.png">
    </span>
    <span class="arrow next"><img onClick="next()" src="img/arrow-next.png"></span>
    <span class="metinalani"><h2 id='metintext'></h2></span> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define your functions outside your procedures. Best to do them upfront.

Comment: Solved! Just changed the ".value" to ".innerHTML" in the javascript.